# ngStyle inline styling with 3 conditions not working

Tags: angular, ng-style

Below code is not working 
I want to check for below conditions

- `event.format === 'Online'` then style `red` color
- `event.format === 'InPerson'` then style `green` color
- if neither `InPerson` nor `Online` then style `#aaa` color

I tried

```js
 [ngStyle]="{'color': event?.format=== 'InPerson' ? 'green' : (event.format==='Online ? 'red':'#aaa')}"
```

Comment: You're missing a quotation after `'Online`. It should be `'Online'`. Is the error or is it a typo here?

Comment: the code is below that statement

Comment: Yes I formatted the code to be read easily but you reverted the edit. And it's a 'yes' or 'no' question. You're missing a quotation mark after the string literal `Online`. Please read your code once more carefully before answering.

Comment: Can you try  `[ngStyle]="{'color':  event.format === 'InPerson' ? 'green' : (event.format === 'Online' ? 'red' : '#aaa' )}"`